# Passing data in REST/JSON Test Cases

Tags: json, rest, soap, soapui

I have a suite called **suite1** and it has two *test cases*. Currently I try to pass a **"correlationID"** from a *JSON Response to a following JSON Request* in a combined test scenario.

*In the first test case:* I use a REST Request 1, and a Property Transfer step

*In the second test case:* has JSON request that require "correlationID"

I managed to fill the Property **"correlationID"** in the Property List of suite1. (I also managed to fill it at test case level when I was trying to figure it out)

But now I would like to access this Property in my JSON Request of test case2.

I have tried `${#TestCase#correlationID}` and `${#TestCase#Properties#correlationID}`. But, the **correlationID** in JSON *Request 2 remains empty* during execution. Any ideas?

REST request of test case2:

`{ "correlationID":"${#TestCase#correlationID}" }`

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very trivial mistake, but adding as answer, in case it may be useful for some one in future.

Change your json request *from:*

`{ "correlationID":"${#TestCase#correlationID}" }`

*to:*

`{ "correlationID":"${#TestSuite#correlationID}" }`

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `testsuite` level property with the name *correlationID*.
2. In the **first testcase**, transfer *correlationID* to testsuite level property *correlationID* 
   (Select target as suite1 and property as *correlationID* from property transfer test step).
3. Now access this property from **second test case**.

```json
{ 
   "correlationID":"${#TestSuite#correlationID}" 
}
```